# reading and writing text files using UTL_FILE package remotely

Tags: sql, windows, plsql, oracle11g, privileges

I 'am trying to read and write files using utl_file package remotely but the oracle server cant read and write on other pc ,so i make a shared path on '\\adel-pc\test', and i want to read and write on that path but i get this error when reading  :

```
SQL Error [29283] [99999]: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 8

  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

and this error when writing :

```
SQL Error [29283] [99999]: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 7

  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

and this is my code  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY utl_test AS '\\10.10.60.11\test'; 




-- reading the file
DECLARE 
p_dir varchar2(2000):='UTL_TEST';
p_file_name varchar2(2000):='IFD18021801IFEEDTL'; --file name
l_file UTL_FILE.file_type; 
l_text varchar2(32767);
begin
l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(p_dir,p_file_name,'r');

LOOP
UTL_FILE.get_line(l_file,l_text);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_text);
END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

EXCEPTION
WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_operation THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cannot open file invalid name');
WHEN UTL_FILE.read_error THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cannot be read');
WHEN no_data_found THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('end of file');

UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
END;




--writing the file
declare 
l_file UTL_FILE.file_type;
l_location varchar2(100) := 'UTL_TEST'; -- capital latter
l_filename varchar2(100) := 'am';

begin
l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_location,l_filename,'w');

FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM hr.EMPLOYEES)
LOOP
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file,i.EMPLOYEE_ID||'     '||i.FIRST_NAME);
END LOOP;
UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(l_location,l_filename,'A');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file,'Additonal lines');
UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
```

so my questions are:

- could I write and read on the shared path or it cant be done using utl_file ?
- why I am getting this error , knowing that I gave read & write permissions to that path.

Comment: I grant read and write privileges to  utl_test directory and also grant read &write system privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the problem is solved ,the problem was in windows system privileges , I had to give full control permissions to the files ,so yes i can write and read on the shared path using utl_file .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you not to do it that way.

First of all, you're creating that procedure in SYS schema, which is - generally speaking - a bad idea. Leave SYS (and SYSTEM) alone; create your own user, grant it required privileges (`CREATE SESSION, CREATE PROCEDURE` and any other you might require), connect to it and then write code you want.

Why are you creating directories *dynamically*? That is a one-time job and should be done once, connected as SYS. Although you might have created those directories (it is a good idea to first `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` command you're about to execute, make sure it is correctly written and *then* actually run it), you did not grant READ nor WRITE privileges on them to anyone, so - nobody can use them but SYS and - as I've said above - don't use SYS for that.

Note that I'm not talking about *operating system* privileges, but *Oracle* ones, e.g.

```
grant read, write on directory some_dir to scott;
```

Finally, as of creating a directory on a computer that is *not* the database server: you should use UNC (Universal Naming Convention) and create a directory literally as `\\adel-pc\test`; it won't work if you map that directory on the server and use its *drive letter*.

As of the error itself, huh ... you posted several hundreds lines of code, it is little bit too much to debug just by looking at it, and we miss other objects you use. No idea, sorry.

Comment: Creating objects is not *"generally speaking - a bad idea. "* it is absolutely always a bad idea. At the very least it creates problems with deployment, import / export, security, etc. At worst it can create support issues if the SYS schema is corrupted. Creating application user accounts is so straightforward, there's really no excuse for using SYS.

Comment: I am creating directories dynamicaly so i can choose wherever location in my pc to read/write in to

Comment: Yes i have created a directory based on unc path

Comment: I think the problem is in system privileges , thank you for the informations